# Why am I getting the wrong output for this program?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int *n_in = &n;
    int r = 0;
    int *r_in = &r;
    unsigned long result1= 0;
    unsigned long result2 = 0;
    unsigned long *result1_out = &result1;
    unsigned long *result2_out = &result2;
    input(&n,&r);
    fact(&n,&r);
    find_nPr(&n,&r,&result1);
    find_nCr(&n,&r,&result2);
    output(&result1,&result2);
}

void input(int *n_in ,int *r_in)
{
    printf("Enter the values of n and r: ");
    scanf("%d %d",n_in,r_in);
}

unsigned long fact_n(int *n_in)
{
    long result_n = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i < *n_in;i++)
    {
        result_n= result_n*i;
    }
    return result_n;
}

unsigned long fact_r(int *r_in)
{
    long result_r = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i < *r_in;i++)
    {
        result_r= result_r*i;
    }
    return result_r;
}
unsigned long fact(int *n_in,int *r_in)
{
    long result = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i < (*n_in - *r_in);i++)
    {
        result= result*i;
    }
    return result;
}


unsigned long find_nPr(int *n_in,int *r_in,unsigned long *result1_out)
{
    *result1_out = fact_n(n_in)/fact(n_in,r_in);
    return *result1_out;
}

unsigned long find_nCr(int *n_in,int *r_in,unsigned long *result2_out)
{
    *result2_out = fact_n(n_in)/(fact_r(r_in)*fact(n_in,r_in));
    return *result2_out;

}

void output(unsigned long *result1_out,unsigned long *result2_out)
{
    printf("nPr : %lu\n",*result1_out);
    printf("nCr : %lu\n",*result2_out);
}
```

So I have used multiple functions.
I have used 3 separate factorial functions for n,r and n-r.
There are no errors in my code .....I think there is something wrong with my factorial functions.
How can I implement all the factorials in a single function.I have used unsigned long for most of the functions.
The conditions are to not use printf or scanf in the main functions and there must be a separate input and output function. 
Please help

Comment: *"I think there is something wrong with my factorial functions."* - Well, then you should investigate whether that's the case or not before posting a question. Besides, it is very easy to find code examples of how to implement a factorial function.

Comment: What's wrong with the output?  What value do you expect?  What value do you get instead?

Comment: Besides. Your code has 4 warnings for unused variables.

Comment: If I give two values of n and r as 5 and 3... I am getting nCr as 12 and nPr as 24....but the actual values are 10 and  60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute `n!` you need to loop from `1` to `n`. But your loop limit is upto `n-1`.
Change the loop limit.

```
unsigned long fact_n(int *n_in)
{
    long result_n = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i <= *n_in;i++) // <= added
    {
        result_n= result_n*i;
    }
    return result_n;
}

unsigned long fact_r(int *r_in)
{
    long result_r = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i <= *r_in;i++) // <= added
    {
        result_r= result_r*i;
    }
    return result_r;
}

unsigned long fact(int *n_in,int *r_in)
{
    long result = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i <= (*n_in - *r_in);i++) // <= added
    {
        result= result*i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @AbhiramMv welcome and accept the answer, upvote will be a plus :P